# Replace text between curly brackets to div with this text

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have input, and textarea. I use vue to set textarea's text to what's in input. I want to be able to write something like `{#123123}text{/#}` to change text's color. Right now, i don't really need any color, i just want to know how to find text between {#} and {/#} and put it div which changes color.

I don't even know where to start, probably i should use some function to find `{`, then check text after it, after that find `}`, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: You can use regex for that, something like `'{#123123}text{/#}'.match(/{#[^}]+}(.*){\/#}/)[1]`. You should check the return from `match` because it can be `null` and using `[1]` on `null` will cause an error.

Comment: Titus, i used as you said, i'm not sure if it works, because i used "setInterval" to log `'{#123123}text{/#}'.match(/{#[^}]+}(.*){\/#}/)[1]`, and 0 is `{#123123}text{/#}`. It;s almost right, but i also want to know what's between `{# }`. Anyway thank you, it almost works!
Yogi, i guess you misunderstood, i don't want to change text inside textarea, i'm displaying it separatly with vue.
Also, if anybody will downvote this question too, can you please say why you downvote? I really want to ask good questions, and i don't want to have about 0 reputation.

Comment: I searched a bit, and looks like regex is right what i need! Thank you!

Comment: In that case, you can use something like this: `const [,color, text] = '{#123123}text{/#}'.match(/{(#[^}]+)}([^{]+){\/#}/);`. It is important to use a comma before `color` (eg: `[,color.....`). Then, you can just use the `color` and `text` variables.

Comment: I've posted an answer, is not Vue but I think you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to do that, here is an example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const textArea = document.querySelector('textArea');

input.oninput = process;

function process() {
  const match = input.value.match(/{(#[^}]+)}([^{]+){\/#}/);
  if (match) {
    const [, color, text] = match;
    textArea.value = text;
    textArea.style.color = color;
  }
}

process();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="{#a83232}text{/#}" />
</br>
</br>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you a lot for answering :3 All i need to know is how to get multiply colors/text. Like `{#123123}text{/#} blablabla {#abcabc}even more text{/#}` .

Comment: Looks like i need `matchAll()`! Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @AndryAndryAndry I'm glad I could help. Good luck.